# Triangle svg with a transparent semi-circle on its side

Tags: html, svg, vector, graphics, svg-path

I'm searching a way to make those svg path, but without luck for now.
I was searching on the internet for a long time ...
I know that css can do this but if someone knows how to build them with SVG it would be really nice.

Thank you

First SVG :
[image: First]

Second SVG :
[image: Second]

Comment: Download an SVG editor such as inkscape and draw them.

Comment: Hi, that's what i'm trying to do, by the way, even with that software the semi-circle doesn't display like those pngs. :/ thx if you can give me some advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about SVG path commands.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#PathData

For example, you can define such shapes by list of some path commands.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
  <path d="M0 0l60 60a1 1 0 0 0 80 80l60 60h-200z"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
  <path d="M0 0l60 60a1 1 0 0 1 80 80l60 60v-200z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: **Pefect** ! I did it using Inkscape but the path  was made from my png edges... And the data are really long. I know some path command, I know how to make the triangle, but the main problem was to cut a side with a semi-circle. I think it's the "a" point... it was not working properly :(.
Thanks a lot ! I'll study it and modify it :). If you don't mind i'll come back to ask you some question if I don't understand some points :). Thanks for helping svg begginers, really.